# Delegate handler for inner list?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<ul id='foo'>
  <li>
    <ul class='a'>
      <li class='animal'>goat</li>
      <li class='animal'>horse</li>
      <li class='animal'>pig</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class='a'>
      <li class='animal'>zebra</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to make a delegate handler for the inner li items (the ones with class 'animal'):

```
$('#foo li ul').delegate('li', 'click', function(event) {
    ...
});
```

I'm not sure how to define the selector though in the delegate definition - what's the right way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#foo').delegate('li.animal', 'click', function(event) {
  //do something
});
```

The initial selector is where the listener for the clicks should live (they'll bubble up to here), the first parameter (`li.animal`) is what elements to listen for a click from.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work...

```
$('#foo').delegate('ul.a li', 'click', function(event) {
    ...
});
```

This will also work, but will attach the handler to every `ul.a` element which is losing the benefits of `.delegate` IMO :)

```
$('#foo ul.a').delegate('li', 'click', function(event) {
    ...
});
```